# How to write equivalent filter in django for the below query

Tags: django

Below is a query which I am using for a search screen. `Mobile1`, `sponsor1` and `status1` are the field inputs from the user. If these fields are not entered then all the values should be returned as output.

Query:

```
       Select * from customer
       where mobile = nvl(mobile1,mobile)
       and sponsor = nvl(sponsor1,sponsor)
       and status = nvl(status1,status);
```

Models.py

```
    class customer(models.Model):
        company = models.CharField(max_length=3)
        mobile = models.CharField(max_length=10)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        sponsor = models.CharField(max_length=10)
        address1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        country = models.CharField(max_length=101)
        state = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        zip = models.CharField(max_length=6)
        email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
        status = models.CharField(max_length=1)
        creator = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        cretime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
        updator = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        updtime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank = True )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just avoid to specify your filtering condition if the user doesn't enter those values.

For instance:

```py
customers = customer.objects.all()

if mobile1:
    customers = customers.filter(mobile=mobile1)

if sponsor1:
    customers = customers.filter(sponsor=sponsor1)

# ...
```

Note that only in the first line I used the model (`customer`) directly, after that I always reused the queryset (`customers`), as you can refine your query in multiple steps.

Comment: @problem is to how to combine these values when all of them have been entered by the user

Comment: No problems, please don't forget to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
# This worked   
 name1 = str(request.GET.get('nam'))
    mobile1 = str(request.GET.get('mob'))
    sponsor1 = str(request.GET.get('spo'))
    status1 = str(request.GET.get('stat'))
    if (name1 is not None and name1 != ''):
        customers_list = customers_list.filter(name=name1)

    if (mobile1 is not None and mobile1 != ''):
        customers_list = customers_list.filter(mobile=mobile1)

    if (sponsor1 is not None and sponsor1 != ''):
        customers_list = customers_list.filter(sponsor=sponsor1)

    if (status1 is not None and status1 != ''):
        customers_list = customers_list.filter(status=status1)
    ctx = {'customer': customers_list}
    return render(request, 'pages/customer_view.html', ctx)
```